# How can I stop my CMS’s CSS affecting my content?

Tags: html, css, content-management-system

I am using a CMS that has been poorly configured with horrific CSS (e.g. H1 is about 12px). How can I load my content without it being infected by this diseased CSS?

I was considering an iframe, but I would want to keep it in the CMS if possible. Would frames work?

Comment: What CMS are you using? Can't you modify the CSS? (Or use a custom CSS file)

Comment: I could but it would break a lot of other pages :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can keep your content within an element with a specific class or id (e.g. `<div class="content">`, then you could adapt a reset stylesheet (like [Eric Meyer’s](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)) to reset everything within that class:

```
.content div, .content span, /* ...and so on */
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Then write all your styles prefixed with that class too, e.g.

```
.content h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

If you’d rather reset everything to the default browser styles (rather than the unstyled settings you get with a reset stylesheet), you could adapt [Firefox’s built-in html.css stylesheet](http://davidwalsh.name/firefox-internal-rendering-css) in a similar way (i.e. prefix all its selectors with the class/id on the element containing all your content).

Bit of a drag, but it might be less of a faff than frames. (I assume the CMS generates your HTML, so it’d be harder to change that to use frames than to work around their issues in your CSS file.)

You might consider changing your CMS — they’re meant to reduce the amount of work you have to do, not increase it.

Comment: I can do this... is there a way to reset everything to default?

Comment: @Mark: depends what you mean by “default”. Reset stylesheets try to remove the default browser styles, letting you build up all the styles you want explicitly. If instead you wanted to restore browser defaults, you could grab [Firefox’s internal html.css stylesheet](http://davidwalsh.name/firefox-internal-rendering-css), which is where its particular default HTML styles come from, and apply that to your HTML content instead, using the method I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any possibility to load your custom css classes? You should load your CSS classes after CMS's CSS classes and override them.